# what are the best techniques for getting back into shape

Tags: exercise

i had an injury recently that prohibited me from working over for several months.  Now that i am healed, i am having a hard time motivating to get back into the gym to work out (as its not a habit,etc).  i wanted to get recommendations for the best way of getting motivated to get back in shape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion is to start slow and don't overdo it.  Set very small, achievable goals that you can measure every week.

For instance, you could start by going for a walk every day during your break time at work and also supplement the walk with some stretching.  Stick with this for more than three weeks (so that it becomes a habit) and then add something else to the list, such as a run or some weight lifting.

You could also sign up for a class at your local gym or community center.  The regular schedule and social/group aspects of the class environment may help keep you motivated and also give you a place where you have to be.

My local gym runs a bootcamp in the Spring, Summer, and Fall, and I am seriously considering taking it myself because I'm having trouble staying consistent at my gym.

Comment: Being with like-minded people is definitely a motivator.  Esp. if they challenge you when you slack off.  They aren't doing it to be mean, it's usually coming from a good place.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to use this opportunity to warn a fellow man about what happened to me when I was in a similar situation.

As you said, I have had a big pause and when I got back to working out, I did a huge mistake. the thing is: my muscles were still 'strong', capable of lifting great weights, but my joints weren't capable of holding those weights.

So what happened? After a 30 minute exercise, when I got to biceps, I started with almost the same weight I was working out with before the gap. My biceps was strong, so it was pretty easy, but after about 8 reps, my wrist "exploded with pain" and I couldn't work out for another 2 months after that. It hurts till today and I think I'll never really get it back to its normal state.

Hope this helps. Take care, learn from mistakes of others!

Comment: Yes! (Been there done that too!!) When going back to the gym, it's perfectly ok to start at a lower weight than when you started. Don't worry though, you will be back to your normal weight soon enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Motivation is tough.....what motivated you prior to stopping? and has that goal(s) changed?  Everyone gets/is motivated differently, I like to write my goals down and visualize what it is I'm going for.  Some people get motivated by being in groups (social), others by watching movies (try a Rocky movie).  What it comes down to is that it's easy not to do something or coming up with a reason why - twist it around, just do it and unless you can come up with 5 good reasons not to, continue.  Make it a routine and over time you won't even think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Motivation?  Determine 3 reasons short term and long term why you want to spend your time in the gym instead of munching potato chips on the couch.

Write those reasons on paper.
Put copies of that paper everywhere - mirror in your bathroom, on your bedroom door, in your car.
Read it everytime you see it and GO TO THE GYM.

In the gym, start slow and progressively build intensity.

Here are some [great motivational quotes](http://race-orlando.com/20-top-motivational-fitness-quotes/).